# jQuery use each in an object

Tags: jquery, each

I would like to use a `each` function in my script but this function is used in an object which means it returns an error... The object I want to use `each` in is `newPlots`.

Maybe you know a trick?

I want to add plots in `newPlots` by using the content returned by AJAX. In plain text, newPlots look like this :

```
                var newPlots = {
                    "City" : {
                        x : 45.834444,
                        y : 1.261667,
                        text : {content : "City"},
                        tooltip : {content : "City"}
                    }
                    , "City2" : {
                        size:60,
                        x : 47.323056,
                        y : 5.041944,
                        text : {
                            content : "City",
                            position : "left",
                            margin : 5
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And the thing I want to do is using `each` function in `newPlots`.

Here you can find my code :

```
$.ajax({
type: "post",
url: '<?php echo $this->Url->build(array('controller'=>'Villes','action'=>'viewresult')); ?>',
data: {
    departements: dptcode
},
dataType : "json",
success: function (ret) {
           // Update some plots and areas attributes ...
           var updatedOptions = {'plots' : {}};
           // add some new plots ..
           var newPlots = {

               $.each(ret, function(index, element) {
                       "Limoge" : {
                           x : element.x,
                           y : element.y,
                           text : {content : "Limoge"},
                           tooltip : {content : "Limoge"}
                       },
               });



           }

           // and delete some others ...
           var deletedPlots = [];

           $(".mapcontainer").trigger('update', [updatedOptions, newPlots, deletedPlots, {animDuration : 1000}]);




},
error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('An error occurred! ' + errorThrown);
}
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work...

Comment: So bascically, you want to get an array of objects??? Your code doesn't make sense and because you don't explain what is your expected behaviour, it is hard to figure it out...

Comment: Change it to -->     var newPlots = $.map(ret, function(index, element) { return "Limoge" : {
                           x : element.x,
                           y : element.y,
                           text : {content : "Limoge"},
                           tooltip : {content : "Limoge"}
                       }
});

Comment: Thank you for your help. Firebug tells me : SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
 

"Limoge" : {

Comment: Are you trying to add an object entry with key "Limoge" multiple times? That does not sound like it makes much sense.

Comment: No it should be "element.name" instead of "Limoeg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you try to extend newPlots is not syntactically correct.

Try doing

```
           var newPlots = newPlots || { };
           $.each(ret, function(index, element) {
                    newPlots[element.name] = {
                       x : element.x,
                       y : element.y,
                       text : {content : element.name}, 
                       tooltip : {content : element.name} 
                   };
           });
```